# Vue values not recognized in template

Tags: vue.js

Trying out Vue for the first time and having some problem with some values not being recognized in the template even though they are set when checking with the Chrome Vue debug tool.

I'm doing this in a Wordpress context if that matters, with an inline template. I stripped down a lot of non-important code in my example below to just focus on the loader. I'm setting the loading value to true and here I'm not changing it anywhere. When loading the page I can see the spinner briefly then it disappears. However the value of `loading` is `true` when I check with debug tool. What am I doing wrong?

Javascript:

```
(function($) {

    var employeesListingElement = document.getElementById('vue-employees-listing');

    if ( employeesListingElement ) {

        var EmployeesListing = new Vue({
            el : employeesListingElement,
            data() {
                return {
                    employees: [],
                    filter: '',
                    errors:  [],
                    loading: true
                }
            }
        });

    }

})(jQuery);
```

HTML

```
<div id="vue-employees-listing">
    <div v-if="employees.loading" class="ajax-loader">
        <p>Loading</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your template should be

```
<div v-if="loading" class="ajax-loader">
```

`employees` is an array.

Comment: Jeez I must be blind :/ Thanks for pointing that out I did not see it!